# Pop up message that occurs until specific condition

Tags: java, swing

I am writing game in java playable on the internet. I am using streams for sending and receiving data.

My question is: How to display a pop up that will inform user that he has to wait.

I wrote this:

```
while(!in.ready())
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not your turn");
```

It works and also prevent user from hitting buttons, but also forces to constantly hitting "ok" button. So is there any pop up that will be impossible to close until "in" stream will be ready? Or any other option that works?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own. Example:

```
class CustomBlockerDialog extends JDialog {
    public CustomBlockerDialog(Frame owner, String text) {
        super(owner, true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 100); // Adjust if needed
        setTitle("");
        add(new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER));
    } 
}
```

And to show / hide (from main window):

```
CustomBlockerDialog block = new CustomBlockerDialog(this, "Not your turn"); // Creation, once

block.setVisible(true); // Show

block.setVisible(false); // Hide
```

Just remember to call them with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom Dialog open it and close when stream get ready:

```
    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

    dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 90));
    dialog.add(new JLabel("        Please Wait..."));
    dialog.setUndecorated(true); // hide close button
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocation(400, 400); // or next line
    //dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);


    while(!in.ready()){ /* wait...*/ };


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.setVisible(false);
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });
```